# I want to alert on when checkbox checked but this code is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to figure out why the alert boxes and console logs don't work as intended when I check a checkbox.
jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#location").click(function(){
        $("input[name='location']:checked").each(function(){
            alert("go");
        });
    });
});
```

laravel blade checkbox code

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
    <h5>Location</h5>
    <ul class="checkbox-list">
    @foreach($store_location as $store_location)
        <li class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="i-check" id="location" name="location">
                {{ $store_location->store_location_name }}
            </label>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique - Also I think there must be a space `input[name='location'] :checked`

Comment: @B001ᛦ a space would signify that a child or grandchild of the input needs to be checked.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn good to know, thank you

Comment: Have you double checked the names of your variable? Is it really `$store_location` and not `$store_locations`? Figure out, if you are using the right variable names there. Good luck my friend!

Answer (score 0):

First you should answer, if the `@foreach` loop works fine and renders the `ul > li` list correctly. I gues it works.

## The JS Code

I've rewritten your code and it works even though there is a problem in your code. You really should use non-identical `id` attributes. You can use classes or what ever multiple times in different HTML tags, but not the `id` attribute. But this does not cause the problem. Have a look on the example:

### Example (in plain JavaScript)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#location').forEach(locationEl => {
  locationEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name=location]:checked').forEach(el => {
      console.log('go');
    });
  });
});


/* 

  "Equivalent" to your jQuery Code:

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#location").click(function(){
           $("input[name='location']:checked").each(function(){
           alert("go");
       });
    });
  });

*/
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" id="location">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" id="location">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" id="location">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" id="location">
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Better:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=location]').forEach(locationEl => {
  locationEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name=location]:checked').forEach(el => {
      console.log(el.value, 'is checked');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="1">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="2">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="3">
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="4">
  </li>
</ul>
```

With `input[name=location]` as a selector you are addressing any `input` tag with an attribute `name` with a value of `location`. And this should just work.

## The Blade Template Code

You are using most probably by accident the same variable name for the variable which should be iterated and the output item of each loop. You should try to rename them depending on the name of the variable which holds the array of your desired information:

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
    <h5>Location</h5>
    <ul class="checkbox-list">
    @foreach($store_location as $location)
        <li class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="i-check" name="location">
                {{ $location->store_location_name }}
            </label>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

If this won't work, consider to upload some part of your rendered HTML code. The one you've uploaded is the blade code, right? Or try to debug your variables that you've pushing toward your blade template. Good luck!